# In Java Swing when i call another class using ActionListener the calling class JFrame is black in color no images,Labels are shown

Tags: java, swing

This is the class i am trying to call(Front_Page.java) from the below class(AddEmployee.java).

In AddEmployee class cancel button is trying to initialize the class but i got a black screen.

What might be the problem i am new to java please help thankyou in advance.

```
package Employee;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Front_Page implements ActionListener {

    JLabel top_Text, img_Label;
    JFrame f;
    JButton b;

    public Front_Page() throws InterruptedException {
        f = new JFrame("Employee Management System");
        f.setBackground(Color.RED);
        f.setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Employee/icons/front.jpg"));
        Image imgcrop = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(1100, 500, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon bg_icon = new ImageIcon(imgcrop);

        img_Label = new JLabel(bg_icon);

        img_Label.setBounds(0, 150, 1360, 530);

        b = new JButton("CLICK HERE TO LOGIN");
        b.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        b.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        b.setBounds(500, 530, 300, 70);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b.setBorderPainted(false);

        top_Text = new JLabel("EMPLOYEE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
        top_Text.setBounds(170, 0, 1500, 100);
        top_Text.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 60));
        top_Text.setForeground(Color.RED);

        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        f.add(top_Text);
        f.add(img_Label);
        f.add(b);

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1360, 750);
        f.setLocation(0, 0);

        while (true) {
            top_Text.setVisible(false);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            top_Text.setVisible(true);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b) {
            f.dispose();
            try {
                new Login();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Front_Page();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

AddEmployee.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Employee;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Manoj Selvin
 */
public class AddEmployee {
    
    JFrame f;
    JLabel img_lbl,top_lbl, name_lbl, age_lbl, address_lbl, email_lbl, jobpost_lbl;
    JLabel empid_lbl, fathername_lbl, dob_lbl, phone_lbl, edu_lbl, aadhar_lbl;
    JTextField top_tf, name_tf, age_tf, address_tf, email_tf, jobpost_tf;
    JTextField empid_tf, fathername_tf, dob_tf, phone_tf, edu_tf, aadhar_tf;
    JButton sub_btn, cancel_btn;
    
    public AddEmployee()
    {
        f = new JFrame("Employee Form");
        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Employee/icons/add_employee.jpg"));
        Image img = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(800, 600, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        ImageIcon crop_img = new ImageIcon(img);
        img_lbl = new JLabel(crop_img);
        img_lbl.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        
        top_lbl = new JLabel("New Employee Details");
        top_lbl.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 23));
        top_lbl.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        top_lbl.setBounds(280,40,500,40);
        
        name_lbl = new JLabel("NAME");
        name_lbl.setBounds(30,100,150,40);
        
        name_tf = new JTextField(14);
        name_tf.setBounds(100, 107, 150, 25);
        
        age_lbl = new JLabel("AGE");
        age_lbl.setBounds(30,140,150,40);
        
        age_tf = new JTextField(14);
        age_tf.setBounds(100, 145, 150, 25);
        
        address_lbl = new JLabel("ADDRESS");
        address_lbl.setBounds(30,180,150,40);
        
        address_tf = new JTextField(14);
        address_tf.setBounds(100, 183, 150, 25);
        
        email_lbl = new JLabel("EMAIL");
        email_lbl.setBounds(30,220,150,40);
        
        email_tf = new JTextField(14);
        email_tf.setBounds(100, 221, 150, 25);
        
        jobpost_lbl = new JLabel("JOB POST");
        jobpost_lbl.setBounds(30,260,150,40);
        
        jobpost_tf = new JTextField(14);
        jobpost_tf.setBounds(100, 262, 150, 25);
        
        empid_lbl = new JLabel("Emp ID");
        empid_lbl.setBounds(30,300,150,40);
        
        empid_tf = new JTextField(14);
        empid_tf.setBounds(100, 303, 150, 25);
        
        fathername_lbl = new JLabel("FATHER NAME");
        fathername_lbl.setBounds(300,100,150,40);
        
        fathername_tf = new JTextField(14);
        fathername_tf.setBounds(410, 103, 150, 25);
        
        dob_lbl = new JLabel("D O B");
        dob_lbl.setBounds(300,140,150,40);
        
        dob_tf = new JTextField(14);
        dob_tf.setBounds(410, 141, 150, 25);
        
        phone_lbl = new JLabel("PHONE");
        phone_lbl.setBounds(300,180,150,40);
        
        phone_tf = new JTextField(14);
        phone_tf.setBounds(410, 179, 150, 25);
        
        edu_lbl = new JLabel("EDUCATION");
        edu_lbl.setBounds(300,220,150,40);
        
        edu_tf = new JTextField(14);
        edu_tf.setBounds(410, 219, 150, 25);
        
        aadhar_lbl = new JLabel("AADHAR NO");
        aadhar_lbl.setBounds(300,260,150,40);
        
        aadhar_tf = new JTextField(14);
        aadhar_tf.setBounds(410, 262, 150, 25);
        
        sub_btn = new JButton("SUBMIT");       
        sub_btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        sub_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        sub_btn.setBounds(170, 400, 130, 30); 
        
        sub_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String name = name_tf.getText();
                String age = age_tf.getText();
                String address = address_tf.getText(); 
                String email = email_tf.getText(); 
                String jobpost = jobpost_tf.getText();
                String empid = empid_tf.getText(); 
                String fathername = fathername_tf.getText(); 
                String  dob = dob_tf.getText(); 
                String phone = phone_tf.getText(); 
                String edu = edu_tf.getText(); 
                String aadhar = aadhar_tf.getText();
                
                if(name.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "USERNAME CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(age.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "AGE CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(address.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "ADDRESS CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(email.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "EMAIL CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(jobpost.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "JOBPOST CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(empid.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "EMP ID CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(fathername.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "FATHER NAME CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(dob.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "DOB CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(phone.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "PHONE CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(edu.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "EDUCATION CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                if(aadhar.equals(""))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "AADHAR NO CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                }
                else {
                    Dao dao = new Dao();
                    int signal = dao.AddEmployee(name, age, address, email, jobpost, empid, fathername, dob, phone, edu, aadhar);
                    if(signal == 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, "User added successfully");
                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f, "Failed Invalid Details");
                    }
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        cancel_btn = new JButton("CANCEL");
        cancel_btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        cancel_btn.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cancel_btn.setBounds(350, 400, 130, 30);
           
        cancel_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                f.dispose();
                try {
                    Front_Page fp = new Front_Page();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AddEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        
        f.add(top_lbl);
        f.add(name_lbl);
        f.add(name_tf);
        f.add(age_lbl);
        f.add(age_tf);
        f.add(address_lbl);
        f.add(address_tf);
        f.add(email_lbl);
        f.add(email_tf);
        f.add(jobpost_lbl);
        f.add(jobpost_tf);
        f.add(empid_lbl);
        f.add(empid_tf);
        
        f.add(fathername_lbl);
        f.add(fathername_tf);
        
        f.add(dob_lbl);
        f.add(dob_tf);
        
        f.add(phone_lbl);
        f.add(phone_tf);
        
        f.add(edu_lbl);
        f.add(edu_tf);
        
        f.add(aadhar_lbl);
        f.add(aadhar_tf);
        
        f.add(sub_btn);
        f.add(cancel_btn);
        
        f.add(img_lbl);
        
        
        
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setLocation(270,80);
        f.setSize(800,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new AddEmployee();
    }
}
```

when i am calling the class i am getting a black screen

Comment: Your application should only have one JFrame.  You should use Swing layout managers and not absolute positioning (setBounds).  You shouldn't be using so many JOptionPanes.  You should go through the Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Learn how to create a [mcve]. The code you posted does not compile since it references classes `Login` and `Dao` which I could not find in your question.

Comment: 1) Don't repeat your question 3 times. 2) Don't attempt to bold the entire text. 3) Use punctuation like "." and "?" when providing information and asking a question. 4) Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 5) Get rid of the "while (true)" logic. Swing is event driven. You should NOT have loops that invoke Thread.Sleep(). The GUI will never get a chance to repaint itself.